# insertar una imagen en pdf report de scriptcase

Tags: php

Estoy necesitando insertar una imagen en una aplicacion pdf report de Scriptcase.
Quiero agregar una imagen al pdf con:

```
{prueba} = sc_image(logo.jpg)
```

donde prueba es un campo de tipo imagen

Answer (score 0):

Me he encontrado varias veces con ese error y al parecer scriptcase no posee una forma de insertar imágenes de forma dinámica.

Puedes usar es una base de datos extra (MySql con soporte de BLOB), en la cual guardarás 
las imágenes en formato BLOB y hacer la petición a esta base de datos. Reconoce las imágenes de forma dinámica solo si está en ese formato.

Otra alternativa que usamos. En mi equipo lo que hicimos para "solucionar" ese problema fue tocar el código fuente.

Eso sí, obviamente es mucho más complejo.

Comment: Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo por programación?

Comment: @GustavoHarreguy Si es programación pura es hacerlo de forma manua con una librería como phpPDF

Sin embargo con scriptcase nosotros lo que hicimos fue poner una variable global con un nombre que solo esté en un lugar y ahí le embebimos la imagen, no recuerdo si fue embeber un html o solo el link de la imagen. Siento no poder ayudar más, eso pasó hace 2 años.
Lo que sí usamos la herramienta de buscar en todo el proyecto para dar con la variable global esa y usamos un campo o imagen html o de texto para tirarle la imagen.